# Ember executes wrong/multiple actions within component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I've written a small array-editor as a component in Ember and it works fine.

```
App.ArrayEditorComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    add: function() {
      var value = this.get('inputValue');
      if(!value) {
        return;
      }
      var items = this.get('items');
      if(!items.contains(value)) {
        items.pushObject(value);
        this.set('inputValue', '');
      }
    },
    remove: function(item) {
      var items = this.get('items');
      items.removeObject(item);
    }
  }
});
```

The template below has been cleared of classes, [check the fiddle](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nadeputa/1/edit) for exact markup.

```
<div>
  <label {{bind-attr for="view.inputField.elementId"}}>{{label}}</label>
  <div>
    <div>
      {{input viewName="inputField" valueBinding="inputValue" placeholderBinding="placeholder" class="form-control" action="add"}}
      <span>
        <button type="button" {{action add}}>Add</button>
      </span>
    </div>

    <ul>
      {{#each item in items}}
      <li>
        <button {{action remove item}}>Remove</button>
        {{item}}
      </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I wanted to add the possibility to add items using the enter-key instead of having to click the "Add"-button so I added `action="add"` to the input-helper and it will trigger the `add`-action when pressing `return`. However, if there are any items available it will also call the `remove`-action on the first item before adding the new one. The `Add`-button still works as it should.

I've also tried `enter="add"` but with the same results.

Here is the fiddle: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nadeputa/1/edit

It seems to have something to do with me having a wrapping `<form>`-element, if I remove that it just executes the `add`-action as it should. I'm however using Bootstrap to style my application so I can't really get rid of the form without it messing everything up.

Is anyone able to explain why this is happening and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to Ember.  Hitting Enter on a text field in the form causes the default button in the same form to act as though it was clicked.

See the [Implicit Submission](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#implicit-submission) part of the HTML spec, specifically:

`hitting the "enter" key while a text field is focused implicitly submits the form), then doing so for a form whose default button has a defined activation behavior must cause the user agent to run synthetic click activation steps on that default button.`

Comment: Fair enough, but why would it choose my remove button as the default when it's not the first nor the last one available in the form? (The first one being the add-button and in my real code I also have a Save-button at the bottom)

Comment: give your Add button type="submit" and the other buttons type="button" and you'll get the behavior you want

Comment: a button with no type specified defaults to submit type.  Your example had the add button with type="button" and the remove buttons with no type specified. So that's why the first remove button was chosen for implicit submission

Comment: To answer the the question `why the first remove button?`: `A form element's default button is the first submit button in tree order whose form owner is that form element.` So it's because your first remove button is your first submit button

Comment: Oh that was nicely spotted guys! Don't know why I had a type there, probably because I copied it from the bootstrap samples or something, but just by removing that `type="button"` it now works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Somehow when you hit `Enter` your input field action and the button of your first list item is triggert but I don't know why.

But I can give you a workaround:

1. Change your `button` tags to `div` tags
2. Remove the action from your input field
3. Put the `form` tags inside your component
4. Add the following action to your opening `form` tag: `{{action 'submit' on='submit'}}`
5. Add a new action `submit` to your actions object

The `submit` action should look like:

```
submit: function () {
    this.trigger('add');
}
```

Here is your modified jsbin:

> http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nadeputa/5/edit

Comment: Changing the buttons to divs feels a bit too hacky for my taste. I also loose the ability to focus the "buttons" which the accessibility-guys will kill me for. The `submit`-stuff might be usable though, but in production this wrapping form contains more elements as well so I'll have to see if I can adapt it with the form outside of the component.